# PC is freezing when gaming

Tags: windows-10, freeze, crash, gaming

Specs:

```
PSU: XFX 550W

Windows 10

GPU: NVIDIA GTX 1070

CPU: Intel Core i7 3770

12 GB RAM

Motherboard: Intel B75
```

So I've been getting really annoying pc freezes when I'm playing games on my pc. I've used DU to delete all the old nvidia drivers and only installed the essential ones again but that didn't fix it. I've also ran memtest86 but that didn't give an error. Some more info about my pc: I got my PC pre-built with the CPU and 8 GB RAM about 3,5 years ago. I added some extra RAM and a GTX 760. The 760 died a few months ago and I replaced it with the 1070.

My CPU max temps are 65 - 70C on Rainbow Six Siege. My GPU max temps are 55 - 60C on Siege

I looked at the Event Viewer and the Event ID was 6008. Here are the Details:

> Log Name: System Source: EventLog Date: 12/27/2017 10:26:15 PM Event ID: 6008 Task Category: None Level: Error Keywords: Classic User: N/A Computer: DESKTOP-JQD5P8I Description: The previous system shutdown at 22:02:30 on ‎27-‎12-‎2017 was unexpected. Event Xml:    6008 2 0 0x80000000000000  3016 System DESKTOP-JQD5P8I    22:02:30 ‎27-‎12-‎2017     34     E1070C0003001B00160002001E00EC00E1070C0003001B00150002001E00EC003C0000003C000000010000003C00000000000000B00400000100000000000000

I can also post the HWMonitor logs if that is necessary. Could anyone have a possible solution?

Comment: have you done a **chkdsk /r c:** not just on c, but all your drives to check for bad sectors.

Comment: I haven't done that at all, will do it now, thanks!

Comment: @cybernard This my first time using chkdsk, When I only type 'chkdsk' in CMD it says nothing is wrong. When I type `chkdsk /r c:`and type Y and restart, nothing happens. Is this because CMD said that nothing is wrong earlier, or should it always do something?

Comment: Did you run chkdsk from and administrative command prompt? The procedure should take hours to complete.  You type Y to restart.  Then you have to manually restart the computer.

Comment: According to this https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-1070/specifications your PSU may not be strong enough to hold the load of your CPU and GPU on 100% while gaming. This may be the cause of the problem. In my opinion you need at least 750W (80plus bronze) PSU.

Comment: @Zerthimon It also crashes on lighter games where the components don't work really hard though.

Comment: @Jack You have a PSU with nominal power max 550W. In order to do some calculations, I'll assume that you have 80plus Silver certification ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/80_Plus ), with 88% energy efficiency at 50% rated load. Calculating: 550 x 0.88 = 484W. NVidia demands 500W in order your GPU to perform. Lighter games can cause trouble.